# k-cycles and permutation of remaining elements in the 100 prisoner problem formula

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, puzzle

The original problem can be found here, [100 prisoners problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem) , where $n=100$ and $n/2 \lt k \le n$. Letting $L(n,k)$ equal the number of permutation on $n$ distinct objects with greatest cycle length $k$. The formula for $L(n,k)$ is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}\cdot(k-1)!\cdot(n-k)!=\frac{n!}{k}$$

The remaining $n-k$ elements can occur in any of $(n-k)!$ permuted orders. This is where I need some clarification as to what $(n-k)!$ means. Letting $r=n-k$, then $(n-k)!$ is just your standard permutation.

$$r\cdot(r-1)\cdot(r-2)\dots(2)\cdot(1)=r!$$

Since the remaining elements can form cycles of sizes from $1$ to $k-1$ then how do we know this equals to $r!$ ? This reference, [On the Number of Permutations on $n$ Objects with Greatest Cycle length $k$](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272528/1-s2.0-S0196885800X00280/1-s2.0-S0196885897905674/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEAaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIG58Ipem72Ei4v9fHaA4sT8N0LD5L0q%2FG%2FmoYye1f8YnAiEA2xFTCN7mc88gf2KoW2mvsg2O9%2Bhr1FXpjIxHBZNqZi4qswUISRAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDOCcYLhtXPJ%2F%2FicvYSqQBe235BcUOPymgiUNLxwdhKpm38SBu%2BLCXNMnpjpAjtDmL1nQQ10HXD9OFH5vh9t6RUnb6LyPCPOVHRcp6MrOArIZbcnqceYEHvKYG0cb3z68WlFkK%2Fys7aZVqAonwNU95qts4MZnj7%2ForHaRV85qmgEI23Pgxvc%2FSQ4fCbCR5RLv%2FFfill6HGTanYbMO%2FgqCcS9z4dC8PiuRAt8O%2Fi%2BTMwqStrM0QsTlVBHRCAWG0XKIot59zUew1ByTnQ15jfMmJ2nTdRFckoC36nEG%2FJ06vkhEw9LblkrrX%2FcYNcZuerQLVtDK02qgcNVsQ60ehHvy3OOgarq%2B4DbGniOgwuGzPMsWrd9j7ufrGJSh0%2FuZPRM7gZC0DVAZVCTcDvI24uBy1GdZ61ugcodSLbv99OAaB%2Fe9XCshiOnRKSRHYApStNG%2BdRjdwZW3cd1jTsg5ezVN%2BLPIIJNXhRvhNgij9aK4%2F7pwADAG%2FHaxwZDN%2BfpBZTVuwW%2B6p671iVt3EmOGi2AtUMV0OZbhQjmYbBxAnUGd1A9kO4fL%2BcaWhkhHwp9sgE0f%2Bqex9bEZmuhQvporxYjvIOgkydoWzunws%2BW8bDAeiPcEKif3HJrT9TVZp2Om83jSSTx4iyx1iIs5zlkiQ4MF%2FdQTLkzWAQVvCe%2F4w4FDz8oU%2Ff7SPqe6LUoPWjxXVldFOued9Ljv7TZMtiEWhhf4T0AnesvprNhHTsUg49wu4UBvi8Avrjk9ezfQhALXRvWW8cLM%2FUMo%2FlwKu63WvCQHitAYjL1M7Oofr0h3RTYflhcEj8bJ3lZZZ40%2FRiooa5Wb3N%2BpTCzWRsyv6NZ8skJ2k%2FK5B9aq5%2BGfLXRs9cemR6SfYL%2Blw548qD6vB1KfPNm2MIWZ9qgGOrEB7WxBeUh7Brck8W8T6ETOHkSUMTYIfG2o9vKK4NY418mo3ZPVCmoT%2BXTntglmOVpnnI7HStPWGk13Rcb%2FeGf33W3vtDjBswrPzhL3wdpi0EgSg1vDg6OXJFXHli72YgSb2yufuEnGIR6scE7LRxwa%2BFC2Vr9mIxgLW4opEl81HI3i6L9jYy2VPdEUELAyxgftdcNSXnQk1bi0nhHlPBLleJmGEA9e7FvwOz3ZyG46leIT&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231004T165736Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYYAD24IYT%2F20231004%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=2124edab035661d07d466b6bf7b71396a884816ea1a37b5d5128658e0a1ba4fc&hash=ddc005883a086636e15a1641ca3e1b3c1b7cca654d30eb901deab2cbfc7290e9&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0196885897905674&tid=spdf-78e49da9-6d30-4dff-84d3-e6749e8dd2ba&sid=c89d187b538a9544e70b09329909b4ac63dcgxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=13105751530202535e51&rr=810ef70129e9fad6&cc=us), states it does by the following formula. NOTE, I reversed the notation from $L(k,n)$ in the paper to $L(n,k)$ in this post.

$$\sum_{i=1}^rL(r,i) = r!$$

Is there some nice explanation for this or am I just mixed up and over thinking this?

Second, and more important to me is the possibility of reformulating the original $L(n,k)$ formula so that you start the formula with the elements that remain instead of accounting for them at the end? I am think of something along the lines of the following and reordering seems to matter but I can't see a way forward when doing this.

$$\begin{pmatrix}n\\1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}n-1\\1\end{pmatrix}\dots\begin{pmatrix}n-k\\1\end{pmatrix}\cdot L(_,k)+\dots+$$

Comment: You are overthinking it.  Sure, we could organize the $(n-k)!$ different permutations of the remaining objects according to cycle-lengths, but there is no need to.  We know that none could exceed $n/2$ since $k>n/2$ elements are already used in the first cycle there can be at most $n-k<n/2$ involved in any additional cycles.  Actually caring any further about the cyclic decomposition of what remains is a tedious waste of time and effort, and quickly devolves into case-hell.

Comment: JMoravitz I am just using this example but really do need to know this for another issue.

Comment: The nicest explanation is the following: if we sum the numbers of permutations with any possible length of the largest cycle we obtain the number of all possible permutations. What concerns the general formula for $L (n,k) $ it can be easily given as a recursive expression.

Comment: user can you show me that summing the number of permutations with any possible length of the largest cycle gives the number of all possible permutations?

Comment: If a finite set is the union of disjoint subsets, then the cardinality of the set is the sum of cardinalities of the subsets.

Comment: user oh that’s it! Great thanks.

Comment: If you'd like I can write this as an answer.

Comment: No that is fine. The second issue was more of a concern.